# Use meld as git diff tool without a wrapper script

Tags: meld, git-difftool

I have installed meld on my system; `$ meld` works from the command line.
I do

```
$ git config --global diff.tool meld
```

and then

```
$ cd path/to/my/repo
$ git config --list
diff.tool=meld
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
<blah blah blah>
```

However, git difftool does not invoke meld.
If I do `git difftool` I get the diff dumped into the console.
This is unexpected given the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool):

> -t 
>   --tool=
>   Use the diff tool specified by `<tool>`. Valid values include emerge, kompare, meld, and vimdiff. Run `git difftool --tool-help` for the list of valid `<tool>` settings.
>
> If a diff tool is not specified, `git difftool` will use the configuration variable `diff.tool`. If the configuration variable `diff.tool` is not set, `git difftool` will pick a suitable default.

I've seen some discussion of using a python or bash script to invoke meld but given that the git documentation explicitly mentions meld as one of the possible tools I'd think this should work without a wrapper.

Is there a way to use meld as the git diff tool without using an external wrapper?